# How does BATS model work?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am using BATS on a univariate time series model. I have observed strange behaviour. I have data from 2016 to till date (weekly level). If actual are considered from 2016 to 2019 May, I have used 2019 June, July, Aug for validation. The model does pretty good job. However if I include June 2019 for training, it gives out a straight line (constant number) for next 80 periods. Can some expert explain this phenomena?i wonder how one month inclusion of actual have such effect on bats model. Using the `forecast` package in R

Thanks

Comment: More info: http://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/bats.html

Comment: i have seen the implementation , i am looking to reason to understand this behavior